# Google Web Toolkit

Tags: web-applications, gwt, struts

Should I use the GWT for a struts web application?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that GWT complements something like Stripes much more than it does struts. I don't want to start some kind of flame/development platform war but in my opinion Stripes is a far superior and easier to use framework than struts, we migrated from struts a year ago and have never looked back.

That said, yes you can integrate GWT with struts without too many hassles, in fact if you do your entire UI in GWT you don't even need struts, you can just RPC straight to your java back end. If you just want to make small components then GWT will work well for that too, and I guess you could *shudder* pass it your struts forms if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GWT would integrate so well into Struts - GWT is more like a framework which you would use instead of Struts.

You could try something like [Ext JS](http://extjs.com/), which (being a pure JavaScript library) I think would be more likely to integrate into Struts.

Answer (score 0):

Struts is a solid framework for everything web-related, GWT is a framework for web application-like behaviour... So, make GWT modules of the parts requiring heavy AJAX functionality, and handle the overall site structural business with Struts, and you'll do Just Fine.